# Is $\sqrt{3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ enough to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})]=2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I think the answer to the question in the title is in the affirmative. But I am not sure how to go about proving or disproving it. Here is what I would like to do.

Suppose $\sqrt{3}$ $\notin$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$. Denoting $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ by $F$, note that $F = L_{F}(\{1\})$ where $L_F(S)$ denotes the linear span of $S$ over $F$. Since $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $L_{F}(\{1\})$, we see that $\{1, \sqrt{3}\}$ is linearly independent (in some vector space over the field $F$, say $\mathbb{R}$). Thus, dimension of $L_F(\{1,\sqrt{3}\})$ is 2. The inclusion $L_F(\{1,\sqrt{3}\})$$\subset$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt{3})$ is clear. I am not sure about the opposite containment. If I could show it, then it can be proved that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})]=2$.

Please keep the discussion elementary, my knowledge of field theory does not go beyond the very first section of the book, Fields and Galois Theory by Patrick Morandi.

Comment: You can think of it as follows. Because $\sqrt3$ is a zero of $p(x)=x^2-3$ and the coefficients of $p(x)$ are in the field $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2)$, the extension degree cannot be higher than two. Therefore it is either one or two. On the other hand, with a field extension $K\subseteq L$ we have $[L:K]=1$ if and only if $L=K$. Can you use that to conclude?

Comment: The thought process in my comment above does rely on the fact that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is equal to the extension degree $[K(\alpha):K]$. Has that been covered? I don't have Morandi, so cannot check myself.

Comment: We know that $\{1, \sqrt 3\}$ is a spanning set, the only question is whether or not they are independent over the base field.  That's the same as asking whether $\sqrt 3$ is in the base field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I got it. The fact that the extension degree is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial has been covered in the book. Because of the minimal polynomial $x^2 -2$, the degree of the extension is at most 2. And since $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, we conclude that the extension degree is more than 1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct. Feel free to post the argument as an answer, also. Your call, of course. No pressure.